In Java Interface contracts, does the @throws tag order should be considered?
Concrete example : https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInput.html#readFully(byte[],int,int)
@throws  NullPointerException if {@code b} is {@code null}.

is before
@throws  IndexOutOfBoundsException if {@code off} is negative, ...

When implementing the DataInput interface, should NullPointerException always be thrown 'before' any IndexOutOfBoundsException ?
Or if the order is a requirement, it should be indicated in the documentaion, with an @apiNote tag for example ?

I'm struggling to think a good reason to throw an NPE by design.

But I also don't think there's any practical reason to care about the order of throws.

If readFully throws a NullPointerException, it's because its argument itself is a null pointer, which precludes checking whether an index can be determined to be in or out of bounds.

Are you asking how the code should behave, or just the order in which code is documented?

@JimmyJames But does the declared order matter when the caller might want to differentiate between a BindException and a more generic SocketException?  Or between a FileNotFoundException and an IOException?  I don't think it does, but offhand I don't know that it doesn't.

@AndrewHenle My Java skills are very rusty but, isn't that all controlled by the structure of catch statements (or lack thereof)?  If you want to catch a more specific exception, you must declare it first in your catch statement, it won't compile otherwise.  I don't think the order of declaration or documentation has any impact on that.

@JimmyJames [Oct 21 at 20:19] : The throws NPE is an example and is in the JDK

@chepner [Oct 21 at 21:36] : You right but the next 'throws' tag is EOFException - if this stream reaches the end before reading all the bytes.. An implementation may check if there is at least one byte to read before checking indexes, and thrown EOFException before if the input is empty. The JDK implementation DataInputStream  doesn't behave this way but ByteBufInputStream (from netty) does.

@JimmyJames [Oct 21 at 20:20] : See my previous comment

@chepner [Oct 21 at 21:56] : My question is about documenting the code :)

As @throws is an annotation in the documentation only, there is nothing in the language itself8 that can force an implementation of an interface to follow the order of @throws clauses or even to ensure consistent behavior.
For that reason, as a user of an interface, you should not rely on any exception having preference over another exception if there are multiple reasons present why a method could throw.
And as an implementer of an interface, I would put readability and maintainability of my code, including having a logical flow, above any ordering of @throws clauses in the documentation.

If you're stuck with a method that has overlapping reasons to throw exceptions it can be helpful to document which is checked for first by listing it first.
foo(-1, null);//will this throw because x shouldn't be negative or because y shouldn't be null?

The draw back is now you have a subtle coupling between the documentation and the code that is easy to forget and put them out of sync.
Whenever dealing with a rare issue it can pay to be a bit cynical and look hard at your design. There may be a way to cleanly sidestep the entire issue and write better code that doesn't force us to deal with this.
